# Compatibility of Akka.net in UAP

Tags: akka.net, windows-10-universal

I would like to add Akka.net to my Windows 10 app, but get this when trying to install the nuget package for version 1.0.5

Akka 1.0.5 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.
Some packages are not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0.

Is this support I just need to wait for, or something I can do to fix?

Comment: Seems to be due to a UAP project targeting .NETCore, while Akka.net is targeting .NETFramework.

Comment: yeah this is a problem all over atm not just akka .net